# How to initiate workflow of a list based on user group permission?

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer-workflow

I have calendar and I have 5 different groups. I have an approval workflow. Now I want to have 5 different workflows for 5 groups but each workflow has to detect the group of the user and send the email to appropriate team leader. I have done sending email and approval workflow. But how can I detect the user group?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to check that natively that I know of from a workflow. There is a third party product that does.

Use the If this user is a member of this sharepoint group action from [Useful Sharepoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/).

Another option would be using some custom script on the page where the user is submitting the item and use a web service call to fetch the groups(s) the user belongs to and populate a hidden column that you could then reference in the workflow.